# Flutter Firebase Analytics Ecommerce Purchase

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-analytics

```
Future<void> logEcommercePurchase ( {String currency, double value, String transactionId, double tax, double shipping, String coupon, String location, int numberOfNights, int numberOfRooms, int numberOfPassengers, String origin, String destination, String startDate, String endDate, String travelClass} )
```

How do I log the purchase of a single item using this API? I have been looking around for days and trying all sorts of things such as adding items to cart before logging the ecommerce purchase but it doesn't work. Do help!

https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_analytics/latest/firebase_analytics/FirebaseAnalytics/logEcommercePurchase.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIt seems like flutterfire still uses an old event to track this, which, I don't know why tracks purchase only for hotel rooms.

[Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Event#PURCHASE) they mention it is deprecated and instead you should use the `purchase` event. I haven't test it yet, but you could try something like:

```
const data = {
             transaction_id: 'T)ID',
             value: 1.00,
             currency: 'USD',
             tax: 0,
             shipping: 0,
             coupon: '',
             items: [{
                     item_id: 'I_ID',
                     item_name: 'I_NAME',
                     item_list_name: 'IL_NAME',
                     item_list_id: 'IL_ID',
                     item_brand: 'I_B',
                     item_category: 'I_C',
                     item_variant: 'I_V',
                     quantity: 1,
                     price: 1,
                     }]
               }
                    
await analytics().logEvent('purchase', data)
```

Comment: Yes I resolved this beforehand but I did this as well. Thanks for helping out!